# Como agregar margenes para generar un pdf en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo una plantilla generada en html a la cual, mediante el uso de c# y replace voy reemplazando unos valores. Esta plantilla ya tiene sus márgenes y su estilo el cual como página html se ve bien, pero al convertirlo a pdf tengo el problema de que no me respeta el margen superior e inferior cuando tengo dos o más hojas.

Voy a poner una imagen para que quede más claro[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]:

El código que estoy usando es uno que ya estaba en el proyecto y es este:

```
HtmlToPdf convertir = new HtmlToPdf();
PdfDocument doc_resumen = convertir.ConvertHtmlString(plantilla_resultado,"");

doc_resumen.DocumentInformation.Title = "Hoja Resumen";
doc_resumen.DocumentInformation.Author = "smiranda";
byte[] pdf = doc_resumen.Save()
```

Existe otra opción para generar un pdf o me está faltando algo?

Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar la biblioteca iTextSharp de la siguiente manera:

```
string codeHTML = '<html>...';
int marginLeft = 10;
int marginRight = 10;
int marginTop = 10;
int marginBottom = 10;

iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
string strContent = codeHTML;
var parsedHtmlElements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(strContent), null);
foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
    pdfDoc.Add(htmlElement as iTextSharp.text.IElement);
pdfDoc.Close();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.pdf");
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfDoc);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```